# Inline textfield and input don't line up

Tags: css

I am implementing an inline form. Users can search for an existing customer or add a new customer.

```
<div id="CustomerInfo">
    <div class="display-field roomy">
        <div id="customerInfoContainer">
            <div class="addCustomerControlsContainer">
                <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;"><input type="text" class="autocompleteinput tt-query" placeholder="Type to search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></span>
                <input class="add-new-customer" title="Add New Customer" type="button" value="+">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why my two elements don't line up?

http://jsfiddle.net/gq2279j2/4/

Comment: Please add: `.add-new-customer { vertical-align: top; }`.

Comment: @emmanuel I guess you were first. Please put your answer.

Comment: Not a need, already has 3 excellent answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this with your style `.add-new-customer{vertical-align: top;}`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2279j2/7/)**

Answer (score 2):

Set the vertical alignment of the button to top:

```
.add-new-customer {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2279j2/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
.display-field.roomy, .editor-field.roomy {
line-height: inherit;
}
```

Instead of the below CSS:

```
.display-field.roomy, .editor-field.roomy {
line-height: 1.9;
}
```

And place your both button in the same span:

```
<span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
  <input type="text" class="autocompleteinput tt-query" 
       placeholder="Type to search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" 
       style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  <input class="add-new-customer context-button noarrow" title="Add New Customer" type="button" value="+">
</span>
```